# Get file extension from curl request or string

Tags: php, regex, curl

I have a cURL request:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://domain.com/file.ext');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
$extension = '?' // How?
```

and want to get the extension of URL, based on content type, but how?

I have read about some regex, but, if my file have multiple dots, or extensions, like:

```
file.renamed.with.multiple.dots.png
file.zip.rar
```

And, if I have a file like `file.ext` and known the content type is `image/png`, but the extension is not `png`?

Thanks!

Comment: This is why we don't use extensions to identify filetypes.

Comment: Well, do you want the _extension_, or the _file type_? If the URL has `file.ext`, then the _extension_ is `.ext`, regardless of the contents of the referenced resource.

Comment: @lanzz I want to get correct extension based on file type

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams this is why I want the extension based on mime..

Comment: As I have answered, `pathinfo($url)` do the job, but, is it safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done with `pathinfo($url)`. I thought `pathinfo` is only to `path`, but not..

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/file.ext';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
$pathinfo = pathinfo($url);
$extension = $pathinfo['extension'];
```

Comment: This does not give the extension based on the content type, it gets the content type correctly from curl, then parses the file name to get the extension. The two can still be mismatched.

Answer (score 2):

if you wish to get the file name check this post.
[Curl to grab remote filename after following location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881034/curl-to-grab-remote-filename-after-following-location)

if you got multiple dots in file you can simply use explode function get the extension

for example

```
$filename="this.is.the.file.png";
$filename_arr = explode(".", $filename);
$count_of_elements = count($filename_arr);
$file_extension = $filename_arr[$count_of_elements - 1];
```

Comment: But, if my file is `name.of.file.ext`, and the extensions is only `ext`?

Comment: @GabrielSantos the explode method is used to only get the item behind the last dot, in this case `.png`

Comment: Yes, I know. The problems: file with multiple extension (`tar.gz`), and file with multiple dots, but which is not extension (`this.is.the.file.png`)

Comment: yes. if you know the mime type you can just put the extension with filename. Also you have to check this function if you are working with images only. image_type_to_extension(IMAGETYPE_PNG), check this link [image_type_to_extension(IMAGETYPE_PNG)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-extension.php)