# PowerShell - Download file(s) from URL that does not include file name in the URL

Tags: windows, powershell, download

I've searched around and tried a few things and have not gotten it to work.
The link would be for example: `http://www.website com/file/[fileID]` (e.g. `http://www.website com/file/1wA5fT`) and a box would appear whether to save the file(s) or not.

I have tried this, from what I can remember and it did not work.

```
$source = "http://www.website.com/file/[fileID]"
$dest = "C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\Downloads\"

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($source, $dest)
```

Edit:

I am able to correctly download the file if I put a filename for the destination. However I need to extract the filename from e.g.

`<a href="http://www.website.com/file/[fileID]">Filename.txt</a></li></div></ul>`

After I get this singled out how would I single out the filename into $Filename?

```
$source = "http://www.website.com/file/[fileID]"
$dest = "C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\Downloads\$Filename"

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($source, $dest)
```

This code would work then.

Comment: What error message did you receive when you tried that?

Comment: `Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:5 char:17
+ $wc.DownloadFile <<<< ($source, $dest)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException`

Comment: Can you provide an example URL? I am guessing that it should be similar to MS download URLs that redirect you to the file. In such a case, you need to retrieve and use the redirected URL.

Comment: related, not in PowerShell, but good explanation on what's going with a working example using `curl`: [curl-to-grab-remote-filename-after-following-location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881034/curl-to-grab-remote-filename-after-following-location)

Answer (score 19):

```
$source = "http://www.website.com/file/someFile.txt"
$Filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($source)
$dest = "C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\Downloads\$Filename"

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($source, $dest)
```

Comment: +1 for showing that [GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) can parse URLs! It's awesome that PowerShell has the the whole .NET library at its disposal, but you can't use it if you don't know about it!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error as you described when I called:

```
$source = "http://www.website.com/file/[fileID]"
$dest = "C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\Downloads\"

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($source, $dest)
```

But when I changed $dest to contain the full path(including the name of the file it worked)

```
$dest = "C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\Downloads\[aFileName]"
```

Comment: Well, I won't know the name of the file downloaded. How would I use powershell to find the dl link that contains the filename?

Comment: Have you tried enter an arbitrary file name? Or is the name of the file important to you?

Comment: I am able to download the file now, I found what is wrong but I need to extract the filename which I would need help with.