# cURL `--remote-name --remote-header-name` options not matching browser behaviour

Tags: curl

I want to download a remote file and get it's filename.

When I download [the file](https://api.foojay.io/disco/v3.0/ids/8e9bf72c045d59ae13d4d88e4b65b01e/redirect) via a browser, it downloads with the correct name of `amazon-corretto-8.402.08.1-linux-x64.tar.gz`.

When I download via cURL:

```
curl --location --remote-name --remote-header-name --write-out '%{filename_effective}' https://api.foojay.io/disco/v3.0/ids/8e9bf72c045d59ae13d4d88e4b65b01e/redirect
```

It downloads a file called `redirect`.

I *think* that the headers don't include the `Content-Disposition` header that [--remote-header-name](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-J) is looking for, based on:

```
curl --location -sI https://api.foojay.io/disco/v3.0/ids/8e9bf72c045d59ae13d4d88e4b65b01e/redirect
```

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 14 Feb 2024 11:52:23 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
location: https://corretto.aws/downloads/latest/amazon-corretto-8-x64-linux-jdk.tar.gz

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Server: CloudFront
Date: Tue, 13 Feb 2024 12:12:25 GMT
Location: /downloads/resources/8.402.08.1/amazon-corretto-8.402.08.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; object-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 0c0251cd4a7521c34adca921995c712a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: LHR5-P4
X-Amz-Cf-Id: rVmqWRTlM__oe599vPtr7Fm5RWMiAnDKSANwDVG85Z5gJvx1AvtUWA==
Age: 85198

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
Content-Length: 118079903
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 13 Feb 2024 12:12:27 GMT
x-amz-replication-status: COMPLETED
Last-Modified: Sat, 10 Feb 2024 00:04:36 GMT
ETag: "033e13fe2c1fe4c12695bcfe82534835"
x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256
x-amz-version-id: NPjrKHalMMJhL_11TPqhQkBXEveVqFy2
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; object-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 0c0251cd4a7521c34adca921995c712a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: LHR5-P4
X-Amz-Cf-Id: VszYYR8DALPT4Wd9hyr_cHU68qMithEL8vtV8I-77EtCTeJlKlySqQ==
Age: 85196
```

I need the name to work out the file type (i.e. `tar.gz`, `bin`) for downstream processing.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curl to grab remote filename after following location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881034/curl-to-grab-remote-filename-after-following-location)

Comment: @0stone0 that looks the same as I'm doing, that's not working.

Comment: There are other answer that might help. But an easy fix, if possible is to use `wget`: `wget --content-disposition $uri`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server does not provide the correct headers for CURL to parse.

---

The easiest solution is to use [wget](/questions/tagged/wget) with [`--content-disposition`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget):

> This option is useful for some file-downloading CGI programs that use **"Content-Disposition" headers to describe what the name of a downloaded file should be**.

```bash
wget --content-disposition https://api.foojay.io/disco/v3.0/ids/8e9bf72c045d59ae13d4d88e4b65b01e/redirect
```

Comment: This is documented as _experimental_ and _buggy_

Comment: Can you please link to that?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html search `--content-disposition`

Answer (score 0):

Using `wget`:

```
wget --trust-server-names https://api.foojay.io/disco/v3.0/ids/8e9bf72c045d59ae13d4d88e4b65b01e/redirect
```

from `man wget`:

> `--trust-server-names`
> If this is set, on a redirect, the local file name will be based on the redirection URL.  By default the local file name is based on the original URL.  When doing recursive retrieving this can be helpful because in many web sites redirected URLs correspond to an underlying file structure, while link URLs do not.

---

```
wget --version
GNU Wget 1.21.2 built on linux-gnu
```

Comment: Where did you found `--trust-server-names`? Can't find that option on the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)?

Answer (score 0):

Using only `curl` in one pass seems not feasible.

If you need to stick with `curl`, add `jq` to parse `JSON`:

```
filename=$(curl -s -H 'Accept: application/json' ${url%/*} | jq -r '.result|.[].filename')
curl -L -s "$url" > "$filename"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the example URL in my question - `Specified Accept Types [application/json] not supported. Supported types: [application/octet-stream]`

Comment: I have already tested as well. Take care of the variable  `$url` that is stripped, so this is one level upper. Read carefully.